# How do I launch my app when a user downloads a file from browser?

Tags: android, android-intent, download, manifest, launch

I'm trying to make a custom downloader UI for Android, and I was hoping there was a configuration I could set in my apps manifest to allow other apps like chrome to automatically open my app when a file of any downloadable type begins to download.

Ideally just replacing the Android downloader would be the goal here.

I'd really appreciate any pointers!

Comment: This sounds like a virus.

Comment: Haha, I guess it would! - It's actually just a code challenge we're doing at work, I found a cool UI design from dribbble and decided to extend it to a working download manager, but just having trouble getting it to receive download intents.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will have to use the intent filters in your activity tag like below:

```
 <activity android:label="@string/app_name" 
            android:launchMode="singleTop" 
            android:name=".DownloadActivity">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW"/>
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE"/>
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
            <data android:scheme="http"/>
            <data android:scheme="https"/>
            <data android:scheme="ftp"/>
            <data android:scheme="sftp"/>
            <data android:mimeType="image/*"/>
            <data android:mimeType="video/*"/>
            <data android:mimeType="audio/*"/>
            <data android:mimeType="text/plain"/>
        </intent-filter>

        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW"/>
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE"/>
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
            <data android:scheme="http"/>
            <data android:scheme="https"/>
            <data android:scheme="ftp"/>
            <data android:scheme="sftp"/>
            <data android:host="*"/>
            <data android:pathPattern=".*\\.apk"/>
            <data android:pathPattern=".*\\.apk.*"/>
            <data android:pathPattern=".*\\..*\\.apk.*"/>
            <data android:pathPattern=".*\\..*\\..*\\.apk.*"/>
            <data android:pathPattern=".*\\..*\\..*\\..*\\.apk.*"/>
            <data android:pathPattern=".*\\..*\\..*\\..*\\..*\\.apk.*"/>
            <data android:pathPattern=".*\\..*\\..*\\..*\\..*\\..*\\.apk.*"/>
            <data android:pathPattern=".*\\..*\\..*\\..*\\..*\\..*\\..*\\.apk.*"/>
            <data android:pathPattern=".*\\..*\\..*\\..*\\..*\\..*\\..*\\..*\\.apk.*"/>
            <data android:pathPattern=".*\\.mp3"/>
            <data android:pathPattern=".*\\.mp3.*"/>
            <data android:pathPattern=".*\\..*\\.mp3.*"/>
            <data android:pathPattern=".*\\..*\\..*\\.mp3.*"/>
            <data android:pathPattern=".*\\..*\\..*\\..*\\.mp3.*"/>
            <data android:pathPattern=".*\\..*\\..*\\..*\\..*\\.mp3.*"/>
            <data android:pathPattern=".*\\..*\\..*\\..*\\..*\\..*\\.mp3.*"/>
            <data android:pathPattern=".*\\..*\\..*\\..*\\..*\\..*\\..*\\.mp3.*"/>
            <data android:pathPattern=".*\\..*\\..*\\..*\\..*\\..*\\..*\\..*\\.mp3.*"/>
            <data android:pathPattern=".*\\.ape"/>
            <data android:pathPattern=".*\\.mp4"/>
            <data android:pathPattern=".*\\.avi"/>
            <data android:pathPattern=".*\\.wmv"/>
            <data android:pathPattern=".*\\.wav"/>
            <data android:pathPattern=".*\\.asf"/>
            <data android:pathPattern=".*\\.mpg"/>
            <data android:pathPattern=".*\\.3gp"/>
            <data android:pathPattern=".*\\.3gpp"/>
            <data android:pathPattern=".*\\.amr"/>
            <data android:pathPattern=".*\\.rm"/>
            <data android:pathPattern=".*\\.rmvb"/>
            <data android:pathPattern=".*\\.ogg"/>
            <data android:pathPattern=".*\\.oga"/>
            <data android:pathPattern=".*\\.ogv"/>
            <data android:pathPattern=".*\\.wma"/>
            <data android:pathPattern=".*\\.doc"/>
            <data android:pathPattern=".*\\.docx"/>
            <data android:pathPattern=".*\\.ppt"/>
            <data android:pathPattern=".*\\.pps"/>
            <data android:pathPattern=".*\\.ppx"/>
            <data android:pathPattern=".*\\.pptx"/>
            <data android:pathPattern=".*\\.xls"/>
            <data android:pathPattern=".*\\.xlsx"/>
            <data android:pathPattern=".*\\.chm"/>
            <data android:pathPattern=".*\\.txt"/>
            <data android:pathPattern=".*\\.zip"/>
            <data android:pathPattern=".*\\.zip.*"/>
            <data android:pathPattern=".*\\..*\\.zip.*"/>
            <data android:pathPattern=".*\\..*\\..*\\.zip.*"/>
            <data android:pathPattern=".*\\..*\\..*\\..*\\.zip.*"/>
            <data android:pathPattern=".*\\..*\\..*\\..*\\..*\\.zip.*"/>
            <data android:pathPattern=".*\\..*\\..*\\..*\\..*\\..*\\.zip.*"/>
            <data android:pathPattern=".*\\..*\\..*\\..*\\..*\\..*\\..*\\.zip.*"/>
            <data android:pathPattern=".*\\..*\\..*\\..*\\..*\\..*\\..*\\..*\\.zip.*"/>
            <data android:pathPattern=".*\\.rar"/>
            <data android:pathPattern=".*\\.rar.*"/>
            <data android:pathPattern=".*\\..*\\.rar.*"/>
            <data android:pathPattern=".*\\..*\\..*\\.rar.*"/>
            <data android:pathPattern=".*\\..*\\..*\\..*\\.rar.*"/>
            <data android:pathPattern=".*\\.pdf"/>
            <data android:pathPattern=".*\\.torrent"/>
            <data android:pathPattern=".*\\.mkv"/>
            <data android:pathPattern=".*\\.swf"/>
            <data android:pathPattern=".*\\.flv"/>
            <data android:pathPattern=".*\\.aiff"/>
            <data android:pathPattern=".*\\.pcs"/>
            <data android:pathPattern=".*\\.mov"/>
        </intent-filter>

 </activity>
```